# Create identification number in order and range delimited to registers

Tags: php, algorithm

A have a list with many full names (>20000) and it increases with each new registration. I need create a seven digits identification number to every register in alphabetical order, so that the conversion start in 0100000 and finish in 9999999. This number must be based on the full name and your order.

When adding new names and that they are merged in the existing base, also generate new numbers merged too.

I have not yet been able to develop a good algorithm that solves this. Then I'll need to create a PHP script for this.

It is a conversion of names to numbers, but with a defined range.

For example

Anthony Felder : 0.459.789
Bianca Mall : 0.989.432
Danton Bishop : 2.986.999
Mario Cortez: 7.883.120
Paul Rudd: 8.788.454
Zeta Jones: 9.987.001

A new name inserted:
Augustus Novell : 0.589.223
Frederic Francis Ford Copolla : 3.765.453

Comment: _"Interleaved"_?

Comment: I want to say merged

Comment: So, are the numbers to be consecutive? Or evenly dispersed among that range? Should number assignments be permanent, or newly added names undo the existing ordering/indexes/numbers?

Comment: "This number must be based on the full name and your order" -> what is the logic behind this? can you show show example?

Comment: Numbers evenly dispersed. After assigning the number to the record it is definitive.

Anthony Felder : 0.459.789
Bianca Mall : 0.989.432
Danton Bishop : 2.986.999
Mario Cortez: 7.883.120
Paul Rudd: 8.788.454
Zeta Jones: 9.987.001

A new name inserted: Augustus Novell : 0.589.223

Comment: If you want that logic then two people with the same name will get the same number

Answer (score 1):

You are going to run into problems, because eventually you are adding to many records that August zzzzzperson will get number 0.989.432 and that already exists.

If you don't expect TOO many new people being added, what you could do:
If Augustus Novell is added to your database - find out between which two names he should be placed (alphabetically). 
Anthony Felder : 0.459.789
Bianca Mall : 0.989.432

Grab their numbers and get a number right in the middle of the two:
roundUp((0.459.789 + 0.989.432) / 2) = 0.724.611

As long as you leave a significant gap between each record at the start. In this example with this gap you can only do this 20 times when you keep adding a new name between Anthony Felder and the latest added name. Increasing the gap, increases the amount of times you can do this. But you have to DOUBLE the gap, just to get one additional name in there.

The limit of 20 is only if keep using the same name 20 times as the upper or lower limit. Would love to hear if there is a smarter algorithm, but I doubt it, without rebuilding indices. Taking the middle of two numbers makes sure you always have the biggest gap between two numbers. (not taking predictive models into account).

I don't like my solution of taking the average, but I *think* it may be the best solution. In other words, unless someone comes up with a better algo, I would try to sort your situation differently. For example, letting go of the need to make the numbers sequential to the alphabetical order of the names (I wonder why this is needed anyway)

EDIT: One other option. Map their name to a number
a = 01, b = 02, c = 03... z = 26, space = 27

Optional, space is a dot, but you can also put a dot every 3 letters (6 numbers)
That means 2 people with the same name would get the same number. You can solve this by having the first two numbers telling you which person it is.
So the first Anthony Felder would start with 01, second Anthony Felder with 02, third Anthony Felder with 03 etc and then start mapping the A (=01).

- You have to define how to deal with other characters such as é .
- This leads to numbers with variable lengths
- This can lead to LONG numbers.
- The limit is 99 people with the same name (or 100 if you start with 00)

Comment: I like your idea. I can take the first three letters and replace them with two digits. All ending in zero. For equal names, I substitute zero for one and the sequence. The letter A can be 01 or 02 or 03 or 04 according to the last name. The letter B can be 05 or 06 or 07 or 08 according to the first letter of the last name... this way until the letter Z

Answer (score 0):

Actually we can create your idea to code
but it need more time (You say that there are 20000 records)

```
    $value = 100000;

 $n= 100000 + $total_db_row; //find total name count from your db table
for( $i=100000; $i < $n; $i++ ) {
   $a = str_pad($i, 7, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); 
   $a = substr_replace( $a, '.', 1, 0 ); 
   $id[] = substr_replace( $a, '.', 5, 0 );

    }

//var_dump($id);
```

then  ,after each insertion you should do...

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM ordered_names;
+----+-----------+----------+------------+
| id | firstname | lastname | sort_order |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+
|  1 | pamela    | edwards  |       NULL |
|  2 | rolando   | edwards  |       NULL |
|  3 | diamond   | edwards  |       NULL |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Next, let's populate the sort order column:

```
SET @x = 0;
UPDATE ordered_names SET sort_order = (@x:=@x+1) ORDER BY lastname,firstname;
SELECT * FROM ordered_names;
```

Let's run that:

```
mysql> SET @x = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE ordered_names SET sort_order = (@x:=@x+1) ORDER BY lastname,firstname;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM ordered_names;
+----+-----------+----------+------------+
| id | firstname | lastname | sort_order |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+
|  1 | pamela    | edwards  |          2 |
|  2 | rolando   | edwards  |          3 |
|  3 | diamond   | edwards  |          1 |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then update php created array with where condition 'sort_order'.

```
foreach($i=0; $i < count($id); i++ )
{
$sql = "UPDATE ordered_names SET sort_order=.$id[$i]. WHERE sort_order=.$i.";
$db->query($sql);
}
```

it will update sort_order col with 0.100.100 to .....
But i repeat it need more execution time for larger records

Comment: The problem is adding records after you've done this - without reassigning numbers to the existing people.

Comment: it will work with existing db data,follow the same step, if you done with insertion ,call it after each insertion , otherwise run fonce for existing data.upvote if the answer is help full